# How to subscribe to change of an observable field

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

until lately I could use bindProperty like shown below or in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679849/how-do-you-create-an-observable-derivative-property-in-dart-polymer-dart/18696710#18696710), but that has changed with 0.8.0 and I don't know how to change my code to get the old behaviour (doSomething() gets called):

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-login" attributes="model">
  <template>
    <template if="{{"model.isLoggedIn}}">
      ...
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type= ... ></script>
</polymer-element>
```

.

```dart
@CustomTag("my-login")
class MyLogin extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  LoginModel model;

  @override
  inserted() {

  void doSomething() {
   ...
  }
```

logoutChangeSubscription = **bindProperty(model, #isLoggedIn, () => doSomething());**

```dart
  }
}

class Model extends Object with ObservableMixin {
  @observable bool isLoggedIn = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Polymer.dart 0.8 or greater, you can also use this convenience form:

```dart
isLoggedInChanged(oldValue) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Notice how you can create a method inside your PolymerElement that uses a name of *yourFieldName**Changed

There's also `onPropertyChange` as defined here: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/observe.html#onPropertyChange

From the docs:

```dart
class MyModel extends ObservableBase {
  StreamSubscription _sub;
  MyOtherModel _otherModel;

  MyModel() {
    ...
    _sub = onPropertyChange(_otherModel, const Symbol('value'),
        () => notifyProperty(this, const Symbol('prop'));
  }

  String get prop => _otherModel.value;
  set prop(String value) { _otherModel.value = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Polymer.dart >= 1.0.0**

```
@Property(observer: 'doSomething') bool isLoggedIn;

@reflectable
void doSomething(bool newValue, bool oldValue) => ...
```

or

```
@Observe('isLoggedIn') 
void doSomething(event, detail) => ...
```

**Polymer.dart < 1.0.0**

Ok, found it

```
new PathObserver(model, "isLoggedIn").changes.listen((e) => doSomething());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the syntax has changed a little bit.
The syntax of the solution proposed by Günter now seems to be:

```dart
new PathObserver(model, "isLoggedIn").open((e) => doSomething());
```